# JavaME read an input from a textfield and display it in another textfield

Tags: java-me

I have read a value from a textfield and I wanted to display it in another textfield, how do I do it, a piece of code will be help ful.

One more thing is I want to do the same thing as above but via a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Item;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.ItemCommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.StringItem;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField;

public class FormDemo extends Form implements ItemCommandListener{
    private TextField tf1;
    private TextField tf2;
    private StringItem button;
    private Command cmd_copy = new Command("Copy", Command.OK, 0);
    FormDemo(){
        super("Name");// Form Name
        tf1 = new TextField("Enter value", "", 32, TextField.ANY);
        tf2 = new TextField("Copy Here", "", 32, TextField.ANY);
        append(tf1);
        append(tf2);
        button = new StringItem("Submit", "Submit");
        append(button);
        button.addCommand(cmd_copy);
        button.setItemCommandListener(this);

    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Item item) {
        tf2.insert(tf1.getString(), 0);

    }
}
```

how to use this

**display.setCurrent(new FormDemo());**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html)? :)

It will go something like `textBox2.setString(textBox1.getString());`

Note: By the way, the title said text field but your question states text box. I did the TextBox anyways.

Comment: Thankyou!, I could have upvoted, but don't have enough reputation since I am a beginner, sry :)